# What methods could be used to preserve scorpion venom?

Tags: biochemistry

As extracting scorpion venom goes, how would one most effectively store and preserve the venom for future research?

My thoughts are lyophilization, however I am not sure that would be the best of all methods in this case. Thoughts?

Comment: Bee venom phospholipase A2 is available as lyophilized product and works well. Why do you need scorpion venom?

Comment: Medical research specific to the Deathstalker scorpion. No other venom substitutions will suffice.

Comment: The enzymes are similarish, so lyophilization stands a good chance at working.

Comment: Scorpion venoms are peptides and not really enzymes. So you need not worry about activity. You can lyophilize and store them in -20. Sigma used to have a [product](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/v1755?lang=en) - Deathstalker venom  in the form of dry powder. They apparently discontinued it.

Comment: I would lyophilize it and store it at minus 80˚C or even liquid nitrogen. Then it should last many years to come without loss of bioactivity.